# How to find native modules in a node.js dependency tree?

Tags: node.js, module, native, node-gyp

I have a node.js application with about 10 direct dependencies which result in a total of 50 dependencies.

I would now like to know if any of these dependencies use **native code** (apart from that of the node.js platform itself of course), such as external system libraries (I've seen libxml used in other projects), own C/C++ libraries, node-gyp build scripts which need compilers installed etc. etc.

Is there an **easy/quick** way to check the whole dependency tree of a given module for such cases?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could simply search for `*.node` files, which is the extension used by compiled addons:

```
find node_modules -type f -name "*.node" 2>/dev/null | grep -v "obj\.target"
```

If you want to check what shared libraries each addon uses, you could use something like:

```
find node_modules -type f -name "*.node" 2>/dev/null | grep -v "obj\.target" | xargs ldd
```

Comment: This will end up including dev dependencies too though.

Answer (score 8):

There's a [native-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-modules) CLI package for this.

```
$ npx native-modules
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The package does not work anymore...

Comment: @jehon what about it doesn't work?